# Running concurrent mongoengine queries with asyncio

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, mongoengine, python-asyncio

I have 4 functions that basically build queries and execute them. I want to make them run simultaneously using asyncio. My implementation of asyncio seems correct as non mongodb tasks run as they should( example asyncio.sleep()). Here is the code:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
tasks = [
                service.async_get_associate_opportunity_count_by_user(me, criteria),
                service.get_new_associate_opportunity_count_by_user(me, criteria),
                service.async_get_associate_favorites_count(me, criteria=dict()),
                service.get_group_matched_opportunities_count_by_user(me, criteria)
            ]

available, new, favorites, group_matched = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

stats['opportunities']['available'] = available
stats['opportunities']['new'] = new
stats['opportunities']['favorites'] = favorites
stats['opportunities']['group_matched'] = group_matched

loop.close()


# functions written in other file

@asyncio.coroutine
def async_get_ass(self, user, criteria=None, **kwargs):
    start_time = time.time()
    query = **query that gets built from some other functions**

    opportunities = Opportunity.objects(query).count()
    run_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("runtime of available: {}".format(run_time))
    yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
    return opportunities

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_new_associate_opportunity_count_by_user(self, user, criteria=None, **kwargs):
    start_time = time.time()
    query = **query that gets built from some other functions**
    opportunities = Opportunity.objects(query).count()
    run_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("runtime of new: {}".format(run_time))
    yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
    return opportunities

@asyncio.coroutine
def async_get_associate_favorites_count(self, user, criteria={}, **kwargs):
    start_time = time.time()
    query = **query that gets built from some other functions**
    favorites = Opportunity.objects(query).count()
    run_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("runtime of favorites: {}".format(run_time))
    yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
    return favorites

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_group_matched_opportunities_count_by_user(self, user, criteria=None, **kwargs):
    start_time = time.time()
    query = **query that gets built from some other functions**
    opportunities = Opportunity.objects(query).count()
    run_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("runtime of group matched: {}".format(run_time))
    yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
    return opportunities
```

The `yield from asyncio.sleep(2)` is just to show that the functions run asynchronously. Here is the output on the terminal:

runtime of group matched: 0.11431598663330078
runtime of favorites: 0.0029871463775634766
     Timestamp function run time: 0.0004897117614746094
runtime of new: 0.15225648880004883
runtime of available: 0.13006806373596191
total run time: 2403.2700061798096
From my understanding, apart from the 2000ms that gets added to the total run time due to the sleep function, it shouldn't be more than 155-160ms as the max run time among all functions is this value.

I'm currently looking into motorengine(a port of mongoengine 0.9.0) that apparently enables asynchronous mongodb queries but I think I won't be able to use it since my models have been defined using mongoengine. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your queries aren't running in parallel is because whenever you run `Opportunity.objects(query).count()` in your coroutines, the entire event loop blocks because those methods are doing blocking IO.

So you need a mongodb driver which can do async/non-blocking IO. You are on the correct path with trying to use `motorengine`, but as far as I can tell it's written for the Tornado asynchronous framework. To get it to work with `asyncio` you would have to *hookup* Tornado and `asycnio`. See, http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/asyncio.html on how to do that.

Another option is to use [`asyncio-mongo`](https://bitbucket.org/mrdon/asyncio-mongo/src), but it doesn't have a `mongoengine` compatibale ORM, so you might have to rewrite most of your code.